# How can I customize the checked state of a checkbox when using svgr in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I'm working on a `React` project and I'm using `styled-component` and `typescript`.

I'm customizing the checkbox like this:

#### Source

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import IconChecked from '@assets/Icons/ico_checked.svg';

interface Props {
  id: string;
}

const StyledCheckBox = styled.input`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #d4dae4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  appearance: none;
  &:checked {
    background-image: url(${IconChecked});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-position: 50%;
  }
`;

const CheckBox = ({ id }: Props): ReactElement => (
  <StyledCheckBox type="checkbox" id={id} />
);

export default CheckBox;
```

#### Question

To use the svg icon without the `<img>` tag, I installed the `svgr` package and set it as an svg type loader through `webpack`.
The problem is that `svgr` has the logic to convert svg to component, so I can't set the checked icon in the following way.

```
 &:checked {
    background-image: url(${IconChecked});
    ...
 }
```

As a result, the check icon(`IconChecked`) does not appear when I click the checkbox after using `svgr`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your `ico_checked.svg` file to `public` folder and use the svg directly from the url like this:

```
 &:checked {
    background-image: url("/ico_checked.svg");
    ...
 }
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-from-public-qzuihm?file=/public/ico_checked.svg) for a live working example of this approach.